# Why can't I use .pollFirst() method for a Set that was initialized as a TreeSet?

Tags: java, casting, set, treeset

Say I've intialized a `Set` as a new `TreeSet`:

```
    Set<Integer> foo = new TreeSet<Integer>();
```

And I want to use the `.pollFirst()` method, because I'm lazy and I don't want to have to use a temp variable because I have this handy method that would reduce what would otherwise be 3-4 lines of code to 1 line.

However, with the following code, the only way to compile my code would be to specifically call `foo` a `TreeSet`.

```
    while (foo.size() > 1) {
        int lower = foo.pollFirst();
        int higher = foo.pollFirst();
        foo.add(higher - lower);
    }
```

So why java doesn't realize that `foo` is actually a `TreeSet`? Should I just cast it as `TreeSet` if I didn't want to intialize `foo` as a `TreeSet`? Or would it be better to just intialize it that way?

Further Testing with Casting:

```
    while (foo.size() > 1) {
        int lower = (int) ((TreeSet) foo).pollFirst();
        int higher = (int) ((TreeSet) foo).pollFirst();
        foo.add(higher - lower);
    }
```

This makes it compile without explicitly calling it a `TreeSet` upon intialization.

Comment: Because you declared "foo" as type "Set" and Set doesn't have a notion of First or Last because a Set is not sorted in any way. So that's why Set doesn't provide an interface pollFirst(). The only way is to downcast your "foo" to "TreeSet" and then call pollFirst() like what you did with ((TreeSet) foo).pollFirst();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `Set` doesn't define a `pollFirst()` method, it is defined by [NavigableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html), which is implemented by `TreeSet`. On the other hand, to answer your question, one good reason I can think of for java to behave like that, is this, assume that later in your code you do something like this,

```
Set<Integer> foo = new TreeSet<Integer>();
...
foo = ExternalLibraryClass.getUnknownSetImplementation();
// At this point, how would the compiler know what 'foo' actually is?
```

where `ExternalLibraryClass` is an arbitrary class from an arbitrary library and `getUnknownSetImplementation()` is an arbitrary method that returns a `Set` implementation. The important thing is that your compiler does NOT have access to the library's source code, therefore it does NOT know what `Set` implementation will be returned every time `getUnknownSetImplementation()` gets called.

**SOME MORE ILLUSTRATION**

Assume,

```
String whichSet = externalWebService.whichSetShouldIUse();
if(whichSet.equals("HashSet"))
  foo = new HashSet()<>;
else if(whichSet.equals("TreeSet"))
  foo = new TreeSet()<>;

// At this point, how would the compiler know what 'foo' actually is?
```

Comment: For purposes of fully understanding your answer, what does the .getUnknownSetImplementation() method do? And I guess I should probably ask what ExternLibraryClass is too.

Comment: is not important what `getUnknownSetImplementation()` does, the important thing is that the compiler doesn't know what it does, check the edit.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand now. I didn't realize that it was supposed to arbitrary, I thought maybe this was part of java, and I just hadn't encountered it yet. Nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

### The Short Answer

This is because that `Set` doesn't define the `pollFirst()` or `pollLast()` methods. You may check the `Set` Interface documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html) and the `TreeSet` Class documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) to verify this.

### The Long Answer

The reason why this happens is because of Inheritance. The child class inherits members from the parent class, but the parent class won't have any idea of its children's members. Now in the `Collection` framework in Java, the `Set` interface is the parent of the `TreeSet` class.

As a result, when we use a `Set` reference to initialize a `TreeSet` object, we miss out on the member functions specifically written for `TreeSet` (which is pollFirst() in your case). However common member functions(first(), last()) to both of them work fine without any issues.

### Example

In the examples [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treeset-pollfirst-method-in-java/) and [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-treeset-pollfirst-method) `TreeSet` reference is used for declaration, thus it works without any problem.